What type of wire-to-board connector is this?
Can anyone identify what type of connector this is? It was used to connect directly to a PCB, for a 24v circuit. Let me know if any more information is needed.




Strongly recommend Davide's tool: https://connectorbook.com/identification.html

Please post pictures of the mate: the male that this female plug plugs into. Please measure accurately the pitch

If the pitch is 2.00mm, it looks like a Hirose DF11-20DS-2C.
